# Air Android - Receiving content from other apps

Tags: android, air, permissions

I would like to enable my app to receive text content from other apps. Everything is working except the invoke event is missing the shared text. 
Do I need to add some extra permissions to receive content from other apps or do I need to modify something else?

The XML code below is from the [Android examples](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html#update-manifest).

XML: Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".ui.MyActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Air: Handling the invoke event:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(InvokeEvent.INVOKE, onAppInvoke);
function onAppInvoke(event:InvokeEvent):void {
info.text = event.arguments.toString()
info.text += event
}
```

I'm building my Android app with Adobe Air 3.6 and Flash CS 6.

Thanks. Uli